# Eloquent: How to find in text fileds via polymorphic relations?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

**Table structure**

```
entity
    id - integer
    title - string
    ...    

person
    id - integer
    name - string
    ...

customers
    id - integer
    body - text
    concrete_id - integer
    concrete_type - string
```

**Models:**

```
class Customer extends Model
{
    ...
    public function concrete()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
    ...
}
```

**Person and Entity models have**

```
public function customers()
{
    return $this->morphMany(Customer::class, 'concrete');
}
```

How to find all customers where type is 'entity' and where entity.title = 'abc'?

I try do something like this,

```
    $obj = Customer::whereHas(['concrete'  => function($query){
        $query->where('title', 'like', 'foo%');
    }])->get();
```

but I have an error:

> ContextErrorException in Builder.php line 825: Warning: strpos()
>   expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

For example, i can do this via native MySQL request:

```
SELECT *
FROM `customers`
LEFT JOIN `entities` ON (entities.id = customers.concrete_id )
WHERE `concrete_type` = "entity" AND entities.title LIKE "%foo%"
```

How to do this via Eloquent?

Answer (score 0):

You work in right way, try this code:

```
 Customer::whereHas('concrete', function ($query) {
           $query->where('title', 'like', 'foo%') 
        })->get();
```

Or you can try another way:

```
Entity::has('concrete')->where('title', 'like', 'foo%')->get()
```

Comment: hmm, no, this dosn't work beacause in this case concrete model type not defined. Person model dont have a title column. I need search text only customers of Entity type.

Comment: Your second method is well work. But problem is that, this solution return Entity models's collection. But i need Customer's collection. 
I updated the question and added the example solution via native SQL request. Look it and you better understand the problem.

Comment: hi, friend. i've found solution. Look my Q answer, we need create the new relation BelongsToMorph, it's working as need it.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrote the answer according to your raw MySQL:

```
Customer::
        ->join('entities', function($join)
        {
            $join->on('entities.id', '=', 'customers.concrete_id')
                 ->where('entities.title', 'like', 'foo%');
        })
        ->get();
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but this solution also not work correctly. Because in the result found all customer types (all records from customers table and joined to each of them entity record. You can call toSql() instead of get() and look, that in request absent general 'where' condition to separate concrete customer type. ))

Answer (score 0):

Laravel now not support `'whereHas'` for `'MorphTo'`  relations.

[Look laravel/framework issue 5429](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5429)

And, if you want to do what is planned, you [can use BelongsToMorph relation](https://gist.github.com/brunjick/3022fee8afa53e45a6b89da3f16b3815).

I added to Customer model:

```
public function entity()
{
    return BelongsToMorph::build($this, Entity::class, 'concrete');
}
```

and after that, request working as need it:

```
    Customer::whereHas('entity', function ($query) {
      $query->where('entities.title', 'like', '%foo%');
    })->get()->toArray();
```